# React setState does not cause re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keycloak

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using the react-keycloak/web library to handle authentication. I want to display different content based on the initialization state of the Keycloak component. Specifically, when the Keycloak component is initialized, I want to show "Original Content," and when it is not initialized yet, I want to display a "Loading" message.

I've tried using the setState() function within a useEffect() hook to update the state and trigger a re-render of my App component. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected, as the component doesn't re-render or update when the state changes.

Here is the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState,} from "react";
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";

function App() {
    const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect", initialized)
        if (initialized){
            console.log("isLoading is set to false");
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }, [initialized])

    return (<>{isLoading ? <>Loading</>:<>Original Content</>}</>);
}

export default App;
```

And here is my console log messages:

```
useEffect false
useEffect false
useEffect false
useEffect false
useEffect true
isLoading is set to false
```

And what I end up with in my page is the "Loading" content. But I expect it to be "Original Content" according to my code and console log.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `return ({isLoading ? <>Loading</>:<>Original Content</>});` This looks like a syntax error. Is that a transcription mistake when writing the question, or does the code really look like that?

Comment: It is transcription mistake. I tried to compress the syntax for the sake of the question size.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is outdated due to edits in the question.

---

Remove the curly braces

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

function useKeycloak() {
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = React.useState(false);
  setTimeout(() => setInitialized(true), 1500);
  return { keycloak: 0, initialized };
}

function App() {
  const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect', initialized);
    if (initialized) {
      console.log('isLoading is set to false');
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [initialized]);

  return isLoading ? <p>Loading</p> : <p>Original Content</p>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I'd double check your IDE is configured for JS / JSX, the linter on stackblitz caught that immediately.

Starting the return statement with a curly brace `{` instead of an HTML tag `<` tells the JSX compiler that's an object, not a JSX element.

Comment: That it is not the problem. I have updated the syntax problem. It was my mistake when I tried to remove the new lines and spaces.

Comment: Ok, then can you please provide a reproducible example? You can use this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pvgw2z?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Answer (score 0):

isLoading should be true every time the script mounts and would be rendered first.
initialized is a promise, so we wait for the response until is available so in this case to be true.
I mimicked the promise by using a set timer.

once useKeycloak is initialized, the useEffect hook is triggered again as its dependancy changes, and isLoading is set to false.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isInitilaized, setIsInitilaized] = useState(false);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsInitilaized(true);
  }, 2000);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", isInitilaized);
    if (isInitilaized) {
      console.log("isLoading is set to false");
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [isInitilaized]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <>is loading...</>;
  }

  return <>Original Content</>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: useKeyCloak is not a function that I wrote in my project. It is coming from "react keycloak/web" library from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/web

It does not return a setIsInitilaized function. It just returns an object and a boolean which I guess I have not understood their logic accurately. According to sample codes over the internet I named them keycloak and initialized. Like here:

https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-keycloak-authentication-react/